# replacement for hover() in jquery1.9?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.9, jquery-migrate

How do I use mouseneter mouseleave instead of hover(). Should i use them both instead of hover()?

```
$('#somegrid').hover(
function () {
    //something;
},
```

What about legacy code - I mean what goes in mouseenter , what goes in mouseleave? i just had one action on hover()

Comment: The `.hover()` method is available in v1.9. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: The question is... why?

Answer (score 2):

Like this -

```
$('#somegrid').on('mouseenter',function(){
 // mouseenter
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
 //  mouseleave
});
```

Comment: What about legacy code - I mean what goes in mouseenter , what goes in mouseleave? i just had one action on hover()

Comment: `$('#somegrid').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function() {...});` will do it, but why not just use `.hover()`?

Comment: link "hover" pseudo-event

As of 1.9, the event name string "hover" is no longer supported as a synonym for "mouseenter mouseleave". This allows applications to attach and trigger a custom "hover" event. Changing existing code is a simple find/replace, and the "hover" pseudo-event is also supported in the jQuery Migrate plugin to simplify migration.

Comment: That's talking about `.on("hover")`, not the `.hover()` method.

Answer (score 1):

look at the [api](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for hover

the hover function is shorhand for:

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

or if you are only passing in one handler:

```
$( selector ).on( "mouseenter mouseleave", handlerInOut );
```

the examples in the api illustrate this well.