# Use of hover throws up jquery-migrate error (jquery 1.9)

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, jquery-1.9, jquery-migrate

Continuation to the question -[replacement for hover() in jquery1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349791/replacement-for-hover-in-jquery1-9)

if .hover() should still work fine with 1.9, I am seeing the below error in console to replace hover with mouseenter, mouseleave.

Code and error screenshot below

```
  this.handle=this.handles.eq(0);
```

this.handles.add(this.range).filter("a").click(function(c){c.preventDefault()}).hover(function(){a.disabled||d(this).addClass("ui-state-hover")}

[image]

Comment: Can you post the complete code that throws the warning? I don't think the warning is thrown because of the ".hover". The warning is talking about the "Pseudo-event".

Comment: difficult to post the entire code, there are so many js files, but reference to hover seems this way in all places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.hover() is still supported, it's the pseudo-event that has been removed.

For example

```
.bind( "hover", function() {})
```

should be replaced by

```
.bind( "mouseenter mouseleave", function() {})
```

ref: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#quot-hover-quot-pseudo-event

Comment: dont see .bind("hover") being referred anywhere in the js

Comment: any other similar references that i might have to check in the code?, i checked for .on("hover",delagte("hover") and now the bind one, none of them are referenced

Comment: it's not just .bind() could be .on("hover"), delegate("hover") etc.
Just try searching for hover in your source code ?

Comment: did you search for 'hover' as well ?

Comment: I do see something like this -f(m).delegate(".t-button","hover" in a telerik js file, this can be the issue right?

Comment: yes, try changing it to delegate(".t-button","mouseenter mouseleave" instead ?

Comment: I see something like this - function(){k("hover",d(this))}); this needs be replaced as well?

Comment: Probably, but that looks like a minified script?
I would suggest to change in the original source

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49644/discussion-between-adarsh-k-and-anderssonola)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to answer this question because you already know what is deprecated and what not, in your question. But what you really want to know is, why is your code throwing a warning, when it -in the code- looks all OK.

So we have to figure out what is going on in your code. For example, what does this piece of code refer to? What is "onHover" in your code?

```
this.element.hover(this.options.onHover);
```

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes
"*Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.*"

Comment: Well, I believe this might not be the code which might be throwing the error, I do see some code like f(m).delegate(".t-button","hover", where the issue mite be present. But how can I make this exhaustive, how do I search for all possible psuedo hover events in my code? Its a huge application plus it has lot of 3rd party code(telerik etc)

Comment: You could do a search through all your files looking for "hover" (with quotes).